# How does Elemental Adept change the damage dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

The **Elemental Adept** feat says that I can treat any 1 on the damage dice as a 2. Does that meant that, if I've chosen fire, when casting the Fire Bolt cantrip I can roll 2d20 instead of 1d10?

Answer (score 22):

It doesn't change what dice you roll, it changes how you read the dice. *When* you roll, any dice that come up showing 1 you treat as if they had rolled a 2.

So if you roll 1d10 and get a 5, **Elemental Adept** doesn't do anything; but if you roll 1d10 and get a 1, then you treat it as a 2 instead.

It's not so useful on a 1d10 because it only does anything 1/10th the time, but it's much more useful on 3d6 and other rolls that have multiple small dice.

Answer (score -6):

Not sure about this... but the wording says, "treat 'ANY' 1 on the damage die as a 2." (Not roll of a 1 or a 2!) ...
 As noted for the Halfing luck, or fighters GWF.
 ... so .. think Witch Bolt .. d12.
10=20,11=22,& 12=22!... Hmmm?

Comment: Hi James, and welcome to the site. Take the [tour] to check out how this Q&A site works. Your answer becomes hard to parse in the second half, could you unpack and explain your thoughts on the topic?